# Capture only letter followed by letter, excluding some words - Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture a letter in a string followed by a letter, excluding some specific words. I have the following string in Latex:

```
22+2p+p^{pp^{2p+pp}}+\delta+\pi+sqrt(2p)+\\frac{2}+{2p}+ppp+2P+\sqrt+xx+\to+p2+\pi+px+ab+\alpha
```

I want to add `*` between the letters, but I don't want the following words to apply:

```
\frac
\delta
\pi
\sqrt
\alpha
```

The output should be as follows:

```
22+2p+p^{p*p^{2p+p*p}}+\delta+\pi+\sqrt(2p)+\\frac{2}+{2p}+p*p*p+2P+\sqrt(9)+x*x+\to+p2+\pi+p*x+a*b+\alpha
```

The letters are dynamic entries, which can be any of the alphabet. I thought about using "positive lookbehind" but its support is limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the result you want with a string replace with callback, using a regex:

```
(delta|frac|pi|sqrt|alpha|to)|([a-z](?=[a-z]))
```

that matches one of the excluded words in group 1 or a letter that is followed by another letter in group 2. In the callback, if group 1 is present, that is returned otherwise group 2 is returned followed by a `*`:

```js
let str = '22+2p+p^{pp^{2p+pp}}+\\delta+\\pi+\\sqrt(2p)+\\\\frac{2}+{2p}+ppp+2P+\\sqrt(9)+xx+\\to+p2+\\pi+px+ab+\\alpha';

const replacer = (m, p1, p2) => {
  return p1 ? p1 : (p2 + '*');
}
console.log(str.replace(/(delta|frac|pi|sqrt|alpha|to)|([a-z](?=[a-z]))/gi, replacer));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const str = "22+2p+p^{pp^{2p+pp}}+\\delta+\\pi+\\sqrt(2p)+\\\\frac{2}+{2p}+ppp+2P+\\sqrt+xx+\\to+p2+\\pi+px+ab+\\alpha";

const result = str.replace(/\\?[a-zA-Z]{2,}/g, (v) => {
  if (v.startsWith('\\')) {
    return v;
  }
  return v.split("").join("*");
});

console.log(result);
```

What this does is to match all 2 or more consecutive letters that are preceded by a `\` or not and in the replace function, if the matched group is not starting with `\`, the replacement is set to the letters group split and joined by `*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `negative lookbehind` to solve this.

```js
const regex = /(?<!\\{1,})(\b[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b)/g;
const str = `22+2p+p^{pp^{2p+pp}}+\\delta+\\pi+\\sqrt(2p)+\\\\frac{2}+{2p}+ppp+2P+\\sqrt+xx+\\to+p2+\\pi+px+ab+\\alpha`;
let m;
let result = str.replace(regex, function(match) {
   return match.split("").join("*");
});

console.log("Match: ",str.match(regex).toString());
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I got: `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",`

Comment: How are you using the regex, can you paste here ?

Comment: Yes correct, older browser even chrome doesn't support it, It's supported only in `ECMA2018`.